# Getting Input Data from a formular and use it as a parameter for a function

Tags: django, forms

Hello I wanted to know if it possible to get input-data from a formular and use this data for another function?

my forms.py:

```
class TextPathForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(required=True)
    language = forms.CharField(required=True)
    stopwords = forms.CharField(required=False)
    search = forms.CharField(required=False)
    filterword = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

my view.py:

```
def textpath(request):
    success = False
    text = ''
    stopwords = ''
    language = ''
    search = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        textpath_form = TextPathForm(request.POST)
        if textpath_form.is_valid():
            success = True
            text = textpath_form.cleaned_data['text']
            stopwords = textpath_form.cleaned_data['stopwords']
            language = textpath_form.cleaned_data['language']
            search = textpath_form.cleaned_data['search']

    else:
        textpath_form = TextPathForm()

    ctx = {'textpath_form':textpath_form,'text':text,'language':language,'stopwords':stopwords,'search':search,'succes': success,}

    return render_to_response('index.html',ctx)

def any_function("need parameter text from textpath() "):
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean? You can always pass `textpath_form.cleaned_data` to your function as an argument or even pass `textpath_form.cleaned_data['text']` and do something with it there.

Comment: If I try:
def any_function(textpath_form.cleaned_data): I get an SyntaxError. 
or def any_function(x = textpath_form.cleaned_data): --> NameError text_path not defined

Comment: No, no. Do `def any_function(data)` and then use it inside your request like `any_function(textpath_form.cleaned_data)`. If you want to store the data, so you can use `any_function(textpath_form.cleaned_data)` outside request, then you need to store it in a global variable or database.